# Multiple images using the same image map - how to return correct image reference on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, imagemap

I have multiple images on a page, all using the same image map. I need to know on what image the user clicked. Trouble is that $(this) returns a reference to `<area>` instead of the `<img>`. Here's the code:

```
<img src="image.png" usemap="#imageMap"/>
<img src="image.png" usemap="#imageMap"/>
<img src="image.png" usemap="#imageMap"/>

<map name="imageMap">
  <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,27,12" href="javascript:;" onclick="up($(this));">
  <area shape="rect" coords="0,13,27,25" href="javascript:;" onclick="down($(this));">
</map>
```

How do I know in the `up` and `down` functions which is the clicked image?

Comment: I prefer to order the images and areas relative to their corresponding parent. This way, you can take the index of the clicked <area> and do something with the <img> that has the same index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There is Only One Map**

If you expect this to make multiple instances of `area` for each `img`, you're going to be disappointed. No matter how many `img` you apply a `map` to, it's still just the same *one* `map` with the same 2 `area` inside. So using `$(this)` inside of the `onclick` won't be much help.

**What You Really Need**

Is the `index` of the current `img` when an `area` is clicked; which is easy to get.

**jQuery**

```
var n;//index of current image 
$(document).ready(function() {//on ready
    $('img').each(function(i) {//get index
        $(this).hover(function() {//and on hover
            n = i;//set index
        });
    });
});
```

Which now means that your `onclick` can now be just `up()` or `down()` since using `$(this)` does not return the current image.

[**Made a fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/filever10/xnL53/) which highlights the current image so you can get a good idea of how it works.

Comment: Thanks, it's a neat trick. I've decided in this case, though, to just use two images - seems more straight-forward and cleaner.